# ant is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ant

- I am running Windows XP Professional Version 5.1 with service pack 3
- I have downloaded the JDK 1.6.0_24-b07 and have tested that it works
- I downloaded apache ant .zip and installed it to C:\ant
- I have set the path to ;%ANT_HOME%\bin
- I have set the user variable name to ANT_HOME
- I have set the user variable value to C:\ant\apache-ant-1.8.2

I have tried the 8.3 format, I have tried everything and I can't get it ant to work. Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I just got to know that there should not be any space between the semicolon and the path we specify. I have been breaking my head how the hell does this happen despite making sure everything is right, let me illustrate this in better way:

ant_home=A:\apache-ant-1.8.2

path=someotherpath1;someotherpath2;A:\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin

Make sure there is **no space** between the **semi colon** and the **path name**.

And we think machines are perfect!!. This sounds stupid I know but it worked for me.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

Can run this command and put the output here?

`echo %PATH%`

Seems that Windows is not taking the right path and it's impossible for him to find the ant executable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Recheck your settings, what's the output of => `C:\> set`, `C:\>java -version` ?
2. Try to set your ant environment via
   batchfile - that's what i prefer for windows machines - and see 
   if it works that
   way, f.e.

---

@ echo off

set ANT_ARGS=-lib C:\ant\extralibs
set ANT_HOME=C:\ant
set ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
set JAVA_HOME=C:\JDK\1.6.0_24
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%PATH%;C:\cvsnt

: DEFAULT
call ant -f  %1

: DEBUG
:call ant -debug -f  %1

: XML LOGGER
:call ant -logger org.apache.tools.ant.XmlLogger -f  %1

: Performance Monitoring
:call ant -listener ise.antelope.common.AntPerformanceListener -f  %1

: Mail Logger
:call ant -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.MailLogger -DMailLogger.malhost=... -DMailLogger.from=BuildServer -DMailLogger.failure.to=... DMailLogger.success.to=... -f  %1

pause

---

Some advantages of starting ant like that :

- ANT_ARGS is a special environment
  variable. Its content is
  automatically added to the invocation
  of ant.
- you may use your own ant settings on
  a machine where you have no admin
  rights
- using a separate folder for your ant
  addon libs and load via -lib option
  keeps your ant installation clean and
  avoids polluting the %ANT_HOME%/lib
  folder

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, all variables configured but the "ant" command won't work.
When printing the path (with echo %path%) , I had this result :

```
;C:\Program Files\jdk1.6.0.31\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;
```

Then I restarted the computer, and somehow this validated the ANT_HOME variable, so now it is working.