# Setting the JVM to use with Ant when using the command line

Tags: java, ant, command-line, compilation

I have to build a project using Ant from the command line. It is an EAR to be deployed on weblogic 8.1 and as such the classpath is set on the correct jrockit, shipped with the 8.1 server. However, the tool keeps using the jre7 (also installed on my machine), going as far as not even starting if i uninstall the jre7 and leading to problems such as "Cannot find class Object", and so on.

Before running ant, I run the `%WEBLOGIC_HOME%/server/bin/setWLSenv.cmd` file in the same console session. Both %WEBLOGIC_HOME% and %JAVA_HOME% are correctly set. The jre7, as far as I know, is not referenced in any environment variable nor in any of the build files. I am *not* permitted to modify the build.xml file, also I can't use Eclipse or any other GUI to build the project.

So, **how can I persuade ant to use the correct JVM**?

Comment: JRE or JDK? Not sure ant accepts to run off a JRE

Comment: JRE, and ant does run, but it fails since all the libraries are way behind.

Comment: Then there is no reason it shouldn't work, unless you don't have `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` in your `PATH`.

Comment: Have you tried running your ant target with -verbose and -debug on the command line?  Sometimes that helps.

Comment: Maybe something here will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955486/run-ant-task-in-different-jvm That said, if you don't control the build file... you are going to have lots of problems... Also - this question has nothing to do with weblogic, sourcing setWLSenv isn't going to help you

Comment: Start ant via batchfile like that => http://stackoverflow.com/a/5558327/130683